# Hexadecimal conversation to Float - Big Endian

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-function

I have a bit of a challenge in converting a hexadecimal string into a float.

Here is an example:

Hex:
3F62 0C3C

Binary: "00111111011000100000110000111100"

Conversation result (float big endian):
0.8829992

Can this conversion be achieved with mysql functions, and if possible - how?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What data type is this stored as?

Comment: Varchar for the hex string